# Solving Ax=B using LAPACK, where x >= 0

Tags: objective-c, ios, linear-algebra, lapack, accelerate-framework

I'm currently working on an iOS app which handles chemical additions to water.  In order to find the smallest possible additions, I'm solving Ax=B where A is a 6x6 matrix and B is one column.  As far as I've been reading, LAPACK in the Accelerate Framework is the best way to handle this.  I've been able to get it working for small additions using DGESV_, but larger ones have some negative values for x.  This is an issue as you can't add a negative amount of a chemical.

So what I need to know is whether there is a function in LAPACK that will allow me to find the minimum solution to Ax=B, where x is always greater than or equal to 0?  If not, is there an alternative solution (other than doing the math myself)?

Thank you

Comment: Unless A is rank defficient, Ax=B has only one solution.  Are you saying A is always rank defficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless A is rank deficient, the solution of `Ax = B` with A square is unique. So there is no way to get rid of negative components in the answer.

If you assume A and B might contain errors that cause a negative component but would like to find a "nearby" solution with all non-negative components, then you could cast this as:

```
minimize |Ax - b|  subject to x >= 0
```

This is a quadratic program.  There are libraries to solve such problems, but LAPACK isn't one of them.

**Edit**

Your matrix is full rank.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is very nice for playing with little problems like this. Your 6x6 has a determinant of 5x10^11, so it's very nicely conditioned.

I'm no expert on QP, but this one has special structure.  For standard form (see [Wikipedia for notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming)), rewrite as:

```
minimize ( x'(A'A)x + (-2b'A)x )  subject to x >= 0
```

Here the quadratic coefficient matrix `Q = A'A` is symmetric positive definite, which (if I am recalling my matrix algebra correctly), makes the system convex and easier to solve: a single global solution is guarenteed. Note `c = -2b'A`.

[Here is a page of QP libraries](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/qp/qp.html), some in C, and some optimized for the convex case.  Perhaps one of them will work for you.

Comment: Right, I'm a bit rusty on my linear algebra, that completely skipped my mind.

A = [
61.5   0.0   0.0    147.4  0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0   103.9  0.0    165.0  0.0
0.0    26.1  0.0    103.0  0.0    0.0
72.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    127.4  0.0
0.0    0.0   72.0   0.0    0.0    190.0
105.8  0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    158.4]

Unless I messed up, I believe this is full-rank.  Do you happen to know of any Objective-C-compatible libraries able to find a nearby solution?

EDIT:  Didn't realize the formatting was going to kill the matrix.  Hopefully that's not too confusing.

Comment: Perfect, some of these libraries look quite promising, I think I'll be able to work one of these in.  I wish I could upvote your answer, but I need 15 reputation for that.

Thank you very much for your guidance